# Ruby scripting on Android?

Tags: android, ruby, scripting

On my desktop, I use ruby if I have to do some scripting. I was wondering if it is possible and practical to use Ruby to do scripting on Android?

By scripting I mean short, generally repetitive tasks, not applications.

70% of my scripting has scripts which are meant to be modified "on the fly", using a text editor, so, I basically need Ruby to run the same as on a Debian desktop.

Is it practical?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for would be [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/) and the associated [IRB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ruboto.irb) which allows you to do some amount of scripting, though I don't believe that it works like Ruby on a desktop, you would likely need to modify your scripts (though to be fair I don't know much about using ruby to create scripts on a desktop so it could be no different but it looks like there's a fair amount of android specific calls).

Comment: I don't think IRB is very practical for scripting. From a very practical sense IRB is polluted each time a script is run and has to be restarted. Scripts while small can often do dangerous things if one is not careful. It just doesn't seem practical to me.

Comment: I will however look into Ruboto. Thanks.